# Pass variable when publishing Asp.Net Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, asp.net-core-2.2

I have the following on an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project file:

```
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build --prod" />
</Target>
```

When publishing the application, using `dotnet publish`, instead of using:

```
npm run build --prod
```

I need to be able to specify if I should run:

```
npm run build --prod.machine-1
```

or

```
npm run build --prod.machine-2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't. Use a custom script or ideally do this as part of a CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: I am using Azure Pipelines but I am not sure how to change the publish script. Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: It's not during the publish, it would be a separate task.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calling `dotnet publish`, you will need to call `dotnet msbuild /t:publish`. These two are essentially the same but the second one gives you access to all of MSBuild's command line arguments.

You can then set arbitrary [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019) in the call to `msbuild` using the `/property` (or `/p` for short) argument. You can then change your target to look like this:

```xml
<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NPMMachine Condition=" '$(NPMMachine)' != '' ">--prod</NPMMachine>
  <PropertyGroup>
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build $(NPMMachine)" />
</Target>
```

This gives the target a default `NPMMachine` of `--prod` but allows you to override `NPMMachine` if necessary.

If you call `dotnet msbuild /t:publish` then the target runs with the `--prod` argument.
If you want to override the `npm` argument, you can call msbuild with `dotnet msbuild /t:publish /p:NPMMachine=--prod.machine-1`.